# Recover RAID 5 with 2/4 failed drives

Tags: hard-drive, raid, data-recovery

This Sunday one of my personal RAIDs disks failed. Stupidly, I thought, whatever, that's what I have a RAID for, I'll get a new one to replace it tomorrow. Barely two hours later it starts beeping again, another drive has failed.

I've looked into recovery methods and it seems like it's a pretty simple, if rather involved process; I can definitely pull it off. The problem is, it seems like you can't do it without a secondary storage with as much space as all the drives in the RAID. My RAID consists of 4x 3TB and makes up about 80% of the data storage in my home, and 12TB of additional space isn't easy to come by.

So my question is, is there any way to recover a RAID without this much secondary storage? The data on those drives isn't critical by any means, so shelling out a couple thousand bucks for an NAS just for this recovery is not an option, however is there is another way, even if it is more work intensive, I would prefer that to wiping it.

Comment: http://blog.antoniac.name/2013/09/recovering-raid5-with-2-disks-failing.html, have a look at that method, you could potentially be able to just DD from the old drive to the new one depending on how the drive has failed

Comment: @Fegnoid Looks promising, the problem is my RAID controller does not have native Linux support. I'll see if I can find a driver that works for me.

Comment: If you are rebuilding your system, please look at a RAID1 or RAID10 solution - as you have discovered, RAID5 is not suitable for use on arays of this size.  Also, if you are going to try and mirror the data from 1 of the failed raid disks, you may want to try using DDRESCUE rather then DD.  It has a couple of big advantages - the biggest is that it will not crash when it hits the part of the disk that fails (and will try to get as much off as it can, and it can be restarted, and even asked to read from the end of the disk backwards), the second is that it shows its progress.

Comment: RAID 5 should allow recovery with up to 1 failed drive. If you have two failed drives, the data are gone. Even in the link by @Fegnoid the recovery was possible because only ONE disk completely failed, the other one still allowed READ commands. Try that technique, it requires only one 3TB disk. I doubt you'll succeed though... be prepared. In the future don't buy all disks from the same supplier, so that the likelihood of failure at the same time will be lower.